# Parse string using regex

Tags: regex, substring

I need to come up with a regular expression to parse my input string. My input string is of the format:

```
[alphanumeric].[alpha][numeric].[alpha][alpha][alpha].[julian date: yyyyddd]
```

eg:

```
    A.A2.ABC.2014071   
    3.M1.MMB.2014071
```

I need to substring it from the 3rd position and was wondering what would be the easiest way to do it.

Desired result:

```
A2.ABC.2014071
M1.MMB.2014071
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  When you're asking about regular expressions, it helps (a lot) to identify the host environment that will be using the regexes; the answers for Perl and PHP are often quite different in detail.

Answer (score 1):

Use this regex:

```
\w.[A-Z]\d.[A-Z]{3}.\d{7}
```

Use the above regex like this:

```
    String[] in = {
    "A.A2.ABC.2014071", "3.M1.MMB.2014071"
};

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w.[A-Z]\\d.[A-Z]{3}.\\d{7}");
for (String s: in ) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
    while (m.find()) {
        System.out.println("Result: " + m.group().substring(2));
    }
}
```

Live demo: http://ideone.com/tns9iY

Answer (score 1):

`(?i)` will be considered as case insensitive.

```
(?i)^[a-z\d]\.[a-z]\d\.[a-z]{3}\.\d{7}$
```

Here `a-z` means any alphabet from a to z, and `\d` means any digit from 0 to 9.

Now, if you want to remove the first section before dot, then use this regex and replace it with `$1` (or may be `\1`)

```
(?i)^[a-z\d]\.([a-z]\d\.[a-z]{3}\.\d{7})$
```

Another option is replace below with empty:

```
(?i)^[a-z\d]\.
```

Comment: I am able to get the match with the expression. How do I ignore the first alpha before the dot ?

Comment: @user3411153 use the last two examples from my answer. Or did I misunderstand your question?

Comment: I have no way to go back and replace the $1. I effectively need a regex which would return a substring.

Comment: try this one: `(?i)(?<=^[a-z\d]\.)[a-z]\d\.[a-z]{3}\.\d{7}$`

Comment: I was trying to see if I could use a lookahead and get the desired result - (?i)(?=.)([A-Z]\d\.[A-Z]{3}\.\d{7})$

Comment: Sabuj - you are a savior. That worked like a charm. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

If the input string is just the long form, then you want everything except the first two characters.  You could arrange to substitute them with nothing:

```
s/^..//
```

Or you could arrange to capture everything except the first two characters:

```
/^..(.*)/
```

If the expression is part of a larger string, then the breakdown of the alphanumeric components becomes more important.

The details vary depending on the language that is hosting the regex.  The notations written above could be Perl or PCRE (Perl Compatible Regular Expressions).  Many other languages would accept these regexes too, but other languages would require tweaks.